# loop from json files and search then get the value via jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a bit of a question. which is a loop.
I have a simple looping which when I clicked some numbers and it will search and loop through out my json file.
here is my code

```
function showSortedRoute(){
    $.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
        var $resultHTML = $("#divResult");
        var result = "";        
        result = '<ul  class = "list clearfix">';

        $.each(data, function (key, val){
            if (val.area_id == getRuoute) {
                var image = val.image;
                var structure_name = val.name;
                var copy = val.copy;
                var address = val.address;
                var access = val.access;
                var type = val.type;
                var getarea = val.area;

                result += '<div class="iconArea">';
                result += '<h4>' + name + '</h4>';
                result += '<h4><b>' + getarea + '</b></h4>';
                result += '</div>';

                result += '<p class="catch">' + copy + '</p>';
                result += '<dl class="detailArea clearfix">';
                result += '<dd>' + address + '</dd>';           
                result += '<dd>' + access + '</dd>';
                result += '</dl>';

                result += "</ul>";  
                $resultHTML.html(result);   
            } else {
                alert("No area ID Found" + getRoute);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

this does not give me any results, saying no area ID found, but in

```
alert("no area id found" + getRoute);
```

and the alert shows displays like four times.
I can check that the value is the same.

code for matching up with integers with json is not working.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your JSON looks like, and what the value of `getRuoute` is.

Comment: this is the value of getRuoute

var getRuoute ='';

and I have a function like this
$(document).on('click' , '#access_code_2196' , function(){ 
 getRuoute = $(this).text();
 alert(getRuoute);
   return false; // to prevent the default action of the link also prevents bubbling 
});

then on seach button its like this
$(document).on('click', '#btnSearchRoute', function() {
   if(getRuoute != ''){
    

   showSortedRoute();
  //$('#areaModal').modal('toggle');
  return false;
  //$("#areaModal").hide();    
  }else{
   alert("you have to pick first");
   return false;
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors in your code:

- `getRuoute` in this line: `if(val.area_id == getRuoute){` seems to be
  undeclared variable
- `name` in this line: `result += '<h4>' + name + '</h4>';` is also
  undeclared
- `getRoute` in this line: `alert("No area ID Found" + getRoute);`
  seems to be undeclared variable

  Here is corrected and optimized version:

  ```
  $.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
      var $resultHTML = $("#divResult"),
          result = '<ul  class = "list clearfix">';

      $.each(data, function (key, val){
          if (val.area_id == 'getRuoute') { // check type and name of 'getRuote', maybe 'getRoute'?
              var image = val.image,
                  structure_name = val.name,
                  copy = val.copy,
                  address = val.address,
                  access = val.access,
                  type = val.type,
                  getarea = val.area;

              result += '<div class="iconArea">';
              result += '<h4>' + structure_name + '</h4>';
              result += '<h4><b>' + getarea + '</b></h4>';
              result += '</div>';

              result += '<p class="catch">' + copy + '</p>';
              result += '<dl class="detailArea clearfix">';
              result += '<dd>' + address + '</dd>';           
              result += '<dd>' + access + '</dd>';
              result += '</dl>';

              result += "</ul>";  
              $resultHTML.html(result);   
          } else {
              alert("No area ID Found" + getRoute);
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: I forgot to include these lines of code
var getText1 ='';
var getRuoute ='';

I used it for global variable, and my search function is this

$(document).on('click', '#btnSearchRoute', function() {
   if(getRuoute != ''){
    

   showSortedRoute();
  //$('#areaModal').modal('toggle');
  return false;
  //$("#areaModal").hide();    
  }else{
   alert("you have to pick first");
   return false;
  }
});


I can get now results but I also get 4 objects, I have like 50+ objects in myjson file but it gives me only 4 results

Comment: and how about `name` and `getRoute` ?

Comment: yes, it is on its proper places now. the results is now my problem, I only get four not all of the same match